# How to make all iBeacon information for each detection?

Tags: java, android, beacon, altbeacon

I deployed 9 iBeacons in the experimental environment. Detecting regional iBeacons using by:

```
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            System.out.println("The number of iBeacons detected = "+beacons.size());
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
```

Output by:

```
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 2
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 4
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 8
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 7
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 9
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 4
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 4
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 5
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 6
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 3
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 6
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 2
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 7
I/System.out: The number of iBeacons detected = 7
```

I confirm that every iBeacon has normal operation.
How to make all iBeacon information for each detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your beacons are not advertising frequently enough for reliable detections.

Each beacon manufacturer has a different default advertising rate -- how often packets are sent out.  The iBeacon standard requires 10 Hz (10 packets per second) but many manufacturers of battery powered beacons reduce this to 1 Hz (1 packet per second) to save battery.

The problem is that not 100% of packets get detected even in the best conditions, which is one of the reasons Apple specifies a transmission rate of 10x the normal ranging rate of once per second to make detections reliable.

To fix this, do one of two things:

1. Configure your beacons, if possible, to advertise at 10 Hz.
2. Change your scanning period to 10 secs to increase the time to collect more packets: `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(10000);`

Comment: Thank you! I will try again. About the second point : where `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(10000);` should  be added?

Comment: add it the first time you use the BeaconManager

Comment: After adding `beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5000);` I can do it. Thank you !